# Show source of a rendered Jekyll page as a link on the page

Tags: jekyll

Let's assume we have a rendered Jekyll post at `domain.com/rendered-post/`.

The source of the post resides in `https://github.com/username/username.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-12-10-rendered-post-title.md`.

Is it possible to automatically include a link to the source code page into the post when it is rendered?

The final result in the post should then be `<a href='https://github.com/username/username.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-12-10-rendered-post-title.md'>View source code of this page</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using the page variable `{{ page.path }}` in my layout.

```
<a href="https://github.com/username/username.github.io/blob/master/{{ page.path }}">View source code of this page</a>
```

renders

```
<a href='https://github.com/username/username.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-12-10-rendered-post-title.md'>View source code of this page</a>
```